# iOS 13 CoreBluetooth. Always get nil on didWriteValueFor characteristic & didUpdateValueFor characteristic

Tags: core-bluetooth, ios13

I have developed some app uses CoreBluetooth. Everything worked fine until iOS 13 was released. And now every iPhone with iOS 13 has problem with sending -> retrieving data. The issue is when I send some command to peripheral it get that command (I see how device starts working) but in my delegate functions like:

```
func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didWriteValueFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?){}

func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateValueFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?) {}
```

I don't see the value that was sent and value that was updated. It just null. In other way the same code when I run on device with iOS 12.4 everything works fine. 
I don't know how to resolve that problem. Somebody met this problem?

Comment: What exactly is nil? The characteristic.value or something else? My app is running fine on iOS 13.

Comment: the value is nil.

Comment: <CBCharacteristic: 0x28105ae80, UUID = 6E400003-B5A3-F393-E0A9-E50E24DCCA9E, properties = 0x10, value = (null), notifying = YES>


Same issue here. @DenisWindover you had any luck solvng this?

Comment: Same problem I'm seeing as well.. IOS14, the value is null https://stackoverflow.com/q/68409316/14414215

Comment: @DenisWindover Did you manage to solve it? any help is appreciated